# jackson custom serializer with custom annotated model objects

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to handle custom annotations in Jackson Serializer. The use case is to do consistency checking between data coming from two different data sources and also having the possibility to ignore certain fields. I could use `@JsonIgnore`, but I need those fields when I do a standard bean serialization. My idea is to implement a custom  serializer which I would use when I wanna do consistency checking. In other words, the custom serializer would do the same for `@IgnoreConsistencyCheck` as it does for `@JsonIgnore`.

Here is an example object:

```
public class Model implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description

    @IgnoreConsistencyCheck
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

Is it possible to implement it by extending Jackson code?

Thanks

Comment: When do you want to check consistency of data (from two different data sources)? After deserialization process?

Comment: yes after serialization. I am using Skyscreamer JsonAssert or JsonEquals for that. My main intention is to not serialize fields which I wanna ignore in consistency checking. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom filter, and then connect it using `@JsonFilter` and `ObjectMapper` config.

Filter code (`CC` stands for 'cosistency check'):

```
class IgnoreCCFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, 
                      SerializerProvider prov, 
                      PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        if (includeField(writer)) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
        }
    }

    private boolean includeField(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return writer.getAnnotation(IgnoreConsistencyCheck.class) == null;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@JsonFilter("ignoreCCFields")
public class Model implements Serializable {
    @IgnoreConsistencyCheck
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description

    @IgnoreConsistencyCheck
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

ObjectMapper config:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PropertyFilter propertyFilter = new IgnoreCCFilter();
objectMapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider(
            Collections.singletonMap("ignoreCCFields", propertyFilter))
);
```

Comment: I found another solution in the meanwhile which solves it elegantly. Jackson has support for MixIn's. So whenever I wanna override or ignore a field I create an interface with those annotations.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setMixInAnnotations(getMixInMappingsFromClasspath());
writer = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

Comment: @user3092750 it would be nice to post that solution as an answer to your question. Maybe it will help somebody in the future. [help/self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)